# Interactive rebase without changing branching point?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I want to do something similar to what the standard interactive rebase does, but I want to use it just to clean up my branch's history and *not* pull in any updates from another branch.  So, I want to keep the 'branching point' the same.  For example, if my branch is B1:

```
--O--O--O--O--O--O------O--O----O--O   master
      \
       O---O--x--x--x--O--O--x--x--O   B1
```

In the above diagram, `O` is a clean commit and `x` is a messy commit I want to squash with the ones before it and maybe change the commit message.  With a normal interactive rebase on master I could get this:

```
--O--O--O--O--O--O------O--O----O--O                        master
                                    \
                                     O---O--X--O--O--X--O   B1
```

Where `X` is messy commits squashed together with a cleaned up commit message.  But how can I get the below?

```
--O--O--O--O--O--O------O--O----O--O   master
      \
       O---O--X--O--O--X--O            B1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rebase on any commit, not just on `master`'s `HEAD`. Let's say your branch point of `B1` is `12345`, then you can interactively rebase `B1` on that commit with

```
# make sure you are on B1
$ git checkout B1

$ git rebase -i 12345
```

Then cleanup the history.

See `git help rebase` for more pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The 'git rebase' documentation deals exactly with your case:

> A range of commits could also be removed with rebase. If we have the
>          following situation:

```
           E---F---G---H---I---J  topicA

   then the command

       git rebase --onto topicA~5 topicA~3 topicA

   would result in the removal of commits F and G:

           E---H'---I'---J'  topicA

   This is useful if F and G were flawed in some way, or should not be
   part of topicA. Note that the argument to --onto and the <upstream>
   parameter can be any valid commit-ish.
```